# iOS Programmatically delete browsing history

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, safari, browser-history

On an iPad (iOS 4.2.1) I need to do the following programmatically (Objective-C, Cocoa Framework): Clean the Safari browser's history, cache, bookmarks and cookies. I have found a method to do this with 'global' cookies but none for the other items. Also I would like to clean up the content of any newsreader that the user may have downloaded. Is there a generic way to do that? The background of my question is this: The iPads will be used in a hotel environment by the guests. I need to make sure they get a clean iPad without the traces and letfovers of the previous users activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the *iPhone Configuration Utility* (free), which allows you to control a lot of stuff exactly for this purpose:

http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

It allows you to handy stuff:

- Lock settings (WiFi, etc.)
- Define which Apps can be used and loaded
- Enable/Disable features on the device
- Much, much more...

AFAIK you can even do a "over-the-air" reset/re-configuration.

Also you might want to enable "Find my iPhone" in case these devices are 3G+WiFi models. This would allow you to track where the devices are in case they are stolen.

Here's a (German) screenshot of the configuration utility. Just to give you an idea.

---

#### Update:

BoxTone seems to be a provider for MDM (Mobile Device Management) which allows you to remote-control/manage all your devices. This works in combination with the configuration utility.

http://www.boxtone.com/

---

[image: Screenshot of the Utility]

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this as a backup solution. Still the preferred way for me would be clean that stuff by myself. If it is possible at all due to the sandboxed nature of the applications.

Comment: Nope. Unless there is an API to access Safari's browsing history (there isn't), you can not change data of other installed Apps. Each App that uses WebKit has its cache and history. - In this case I highly doubt that you can delete the browsing history of Safari unless you jailbreak your devices and do it "the unofficial way".

Answer (score 1):

Just restore from a clean backup every time a user returns the device.

Comment: The devices will stay in the rooms and will not be returned by the guests so this solution is not practical. I can find out if the guest changed and then I am expected to clean the device up. Is it maybe possible to turn those features off? No browsing history, disable setting bookmarks, ...